# Accessing xampp server from mobile

Tags: php, mobile, xampp, lan

A computer that is connected to the LAN is able to connect to my application, but mobile devices can't.

The mobile device is connected to the same WIFI as the other computers.
I entered the ipv4 address in the command line of the mobile browser (and also navigated to the directory of the php file (the application)) and got this error:

> ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Again, the host computer can connect as well as another computer on the LAN.

Only mobile devices cannot.

Comment: Im using XAMPP, which is online and avaiable in port 80

Comment: If your mobile device is not a network device on your network this will not work. Your web server will need a public address.

Comment: Are you sure it's on the same network? WiFi networks tend to be on a different network especially in a business or public location. if so check if your vhost is properly configured.